# scantoken adds unwanted space

Tags: latex3, scantokens

My goal is to evaluate the content of a LaTeX3 string. Unfortunately, it adds some unwanted space at the end. Do you know how to avoid this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setMe}{m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_test_a_str {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printMe}{m}{
  \exp_args:Nx \scantokens {\use:c{l_test_#1_str}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setMe{Hello $\delta$.}

This should display some math, without any space before or after the quote symbols: ``\printMe{a}''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\use:c` is the wrong function. It should be `\str_use:c`, because you're passing a string name. Consistency with data types is very important. Of course, `\tl_rescan:nv` (as suggested) is much better for the task at hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

`\scantokens` is a tricky beast, a couple of possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setMe}{m}{
  \str_set:Nn \l_test_a_str {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printMe}{m}{
  \exp_args:Nx \scantokens {\use:c{l_test_#1_str}
                             \noexpand\noexpand}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\tl_rescan:nn {nv}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printMeB}{m}{
  \tl_rescan:nv {}{l_test_#1_str}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setMe{Hello $\delta$.}

This should display some math, without any space before or after the quote symbols: ``\printMe{a}''.

This should display some math, without any space before or after the quote symbols: ``\printMeB{a}''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never realized that `:v` was doing a csname first. So I’m curious now, what is the difference between `:v` ans `:c`? I tried to generate a variant of `\tl_rescan:nc` earlier, but it failed with an error saying generating `:c` from `:n` was deprecated.

Comment: `v` is a csname  version of `V`  so `c`  with  `{foo}` is `\foo`  but `v`  with `{foo}` is  `\expandafter ... \foo` or `\expandafter ... \the\foo` or whatever is needed to pass on the value rather than the csname token @tobiasBora

Comment: @tobiasBora if I recall correctly that don't use `:c` message does suggest using `:v` instead :-)

Comment: I just checked a few things. The two `\noexpand` aren't correct (and three weren't as well). It should be four `\noexpand` in the `\exp_args:Nx` version... If you put only two any following macro wouldn't be expanded (same for 3).

Comment: A simple `\relax` would work as well, so I'd say `\exp_args:Nx \scantokens {\use:c{l_test_#1_str}\relax}` should be used. In sumary, anything that makes TeX ignore a following space would work (so any control sequence), as long as it has minimal side-effects (a single `\noexpand` after the `\exp_args:Nx`-process would affect the following token, and if that's a macro turn it into a `\relax`, two `\noexpand`s are just equal to a single `\relax`, in your answer the one `\noexpand` after `\exp_args:Nx` works becaues the `'` just isn't affected by it).

Comment: Yet another possibility would be to put a `\c_percent_str` inside your `\scantokens` contents, provided that `%` has category comment in the scope `\scantokens` works in.